# Testing backbone.js application with jasmine - view with bound element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

In my application I have a view which comes bound to an html element already in the DOM

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
  ...
  el: '#myElement',
  ...
});
```

I've a problem with the following jasmine test:

```
beforeEach(function(){
            //fixiture created with jasmin-jquery.js plugin
        setFixtures('<div id="myElement"></div>');

        this.myView = new MyView({model: new Model()); 
    });
describe('when instantiated', function(){
it('should be associated to #myElement', function(){
            expect(this.app.el).toBeDefined();
            expect(this.app.el).toBe($('#myElement'));
        });
});
```

the test fails and it turns out that this.app.el == ''

Am I wrong or this shouldn't be the correct behavior?

Comment: the problem seems to be that the backbone view can't find the fixture created by jasmine-jquery.js: if I pass the element to the constructor of the collection (ie: el: $('#myElement')) evrithing works fine

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your fixture include the "myElement" id so your view can hook it up?

```
setFixtures('<div id="myElement"></div>');
```